# enthought package manager error

Tags: windows, enthought, package-managers, canopy

After updating to Enthought Canopy 1.4 on Windows 7 I cannot access packages with Package Manager. It fails with "Could not connect to Canopy server." I don't have proxies: "NO_PROXY: localhost, 127.0.0.1". This happens on two different computers Win32 and Win64. (With the same settings on a Mac in the same network there is no problem!) Wonder if other people experience the same problem. Can you please help?

Comment: Please submit a bug report via the Canopy help menu.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by logging out from and logging again in to my Canopy account. On one machine I had to quit Canopy and to start it again before this worked. It seemingly has to do with handling of passwords by Canopy.